# Android class not found NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, classnotfound

I need your help to resolve a class problem. When I run my virtual device, and when I click on button to call a method, that doesn't work.
I tryed with different libraries like itext and justformPDF (last one is java libraries).

I indicated it in build path but I have a mistake ... The class is not found :(

Thanks for your help :)

You can see the logcat here : [www.aclebpokerclub.com/Application/LogCat.png](http://www.aclebpokerclub.com/Application/LogCat.png)

Comment: in your build path under "order and export" you will have to check them all (or atleast the jars/libraries for which you have noclassdef).. have you done it?

Comment: right click on your project -> go to properties -> go to java build path -> go to order and export -> then select library -> save

Comment: Yes I did, but do you need more information that logcat , screenshot ? to find the bug. Firrst I used itext pdf becaus I thought tat it was the librairies who didn't work, but it's the same problem ...